# Find all unique combinations of removing a duplicate in groups from a data set

Tags: r, nested-loops

I am trying to figure out how to create code in R to find all combinations of how a duplicate can be removed from a dataset from different groups and create a list of all the dataset combinations.

An example of a test data:

```
groups <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
value <- c(1, 2, "duplicate1", "duplicate1", 4, "duplicate2", "duplicate2", 5, 6)
id <- 1:9
dat <- data.frame(
id = id,
groups = groups,
value = value
)
```

An example of desired output:

```
list <- dataset1, dataset2, dataset3
```

Dataset1 of one combination how you could remove the duplicates from the groups:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | duplicate1 |
| B | 4 |
| C | duplicate2 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 6 |

Another combination, dataset2:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | duplicate1 |
| B | 4 |
| C | duplicate2 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 6 |

How would I find all combinations of ways to remove duplicate1 and duplicate2 within the groups of A, B and C? I would like to have all combinations of datasets returned as a list()

I have tried for (nested) loops, combn(), expand.grid() - but I am not clever enough to think of a solution.
And tried to see similar solutions, but those I have found do not delete a row and duplicate from a dataset.

Thank you so much in advance for helping.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of your expected output, rather than a simple description, just as you have done for your test data.

Comment: Thank Limey. I have tried to illustrate the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I think I understand now.  You want to create more than one "de-duplicated" data frame, one for each poissible combination of rows with a duplicated `value`.

In preparation, ensure we have a way to uniquely identify each row of the input dataset.  Row number is the obvious choice.

```
datCopy <- dat %>% 
  # Create a temporary index of row numbers to ensure unique identifiability
  mutate(Row = row_number())
```

Now identify the duplicated rows and form a grid of all possible combinations of corresponding row numbers

```
combos <- datCopy %>% 
  # Identify duplicate values
  group_by(value) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  # Create a grid of all combinations of duplicated row ids
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      .x %>% pull(Row)
    }
  ) %>% 
  expand.grid() %>% 
  # Label the combinations
  mutate(ComboID = row_number()) %>% 
  # Convert from one column per duplicated value to one row
  # per duplicated value.  There is no need to identify which
  # row corresponds to which duplicated value, so drop name
  rowwise() %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("Var"),
    values_to = "Row",
  ) %>% 
  select(-name)

combos
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  ComboID   Row
    <int> <int>
1       1     3
2       1     6
3       2     4
4       2     6
5       3     3
6       3     7
7       4     4
8       4     7
```

At this point, we've done the hard work.  We can see there are for possible combinations of row exclusions (2 options for `duplicate1`, another 2 for `duplicate2`, or 2 x 2 = 4 in total).  Within each distinct value of `ComboID`, the values of `Row` identify which rows to exclude.

So now loop through `combos`, processing (the copy of) `dat` to exclude rows as required.

```
combos %>% 
  group_by(ComboID) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      datCopy %>% anti_join(.x, by = "Row") %>% 
      select(-Row)
    }
  )
[[1]]
  id groups      value
1  1      A          1
2  2      A          2
3  4      B duplicate1
4  5      B          4
5  7      C duplicate2
6  8      C          5
7  9      C          6

[[2]]
  id groups      value
1  1      A          1
2  2      A          2
3  3      A duplicate1
4  5      B          4
5  7      C duplicate2
6  8      C          5
7  9      C          6

[[3]]
  id groups      value
1  1      A          1
2  2      A          2
3  4      B duplicate1
4  5      B          4
5  6      B duplicate2
6  8      C          5
7  9      C          6

[[4]]
  id groups      value
1  1      A          1
2  2      A          2
3  3      A duplicate1
4  5      B          4
5  6      B duplicate2
6  8      C          5
7  9      C          6
```

I believe this is what you want.

The algorithm should be robust with respect to the number of duplicated values and the number of times each value is duplicated.

I've broken the algorithm down into smaller steps.  You can combine them all into a single pipe if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

The apparent complication here is that duplicates may span `groups`.  So simply ignore `groups` (and `id`) when identifying the duplicates.

First, `arrange` by `value`.  Then flag duplicates.  Sort back into the original order, filter duplicates and drop the flag.

```
dat %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  mutate(Duplicate = ifelse(row_number() == 1, FALSE, value == lag(value))) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  filter(!Duplicate) %>% 
  select(-Duplicate)
  id groups      value
1  1      A          1
2  2      A          2
3  3      A duplicate1
4  5      B          4
5  6      B duplicate2
6  8      C          5
7  9      C          6
```

This matches your (alternative) expected output.

Comment: Thank you, I have made a similar code for this, but the solution does not solve the combination issue which for me makes it rather complicated.

Comment: I believe this matches your expected output, so if it is not what you need, please explain why and amend your question with further detail.

Comment: It is indeed one of the combinations. Now I have edited the question and added another example of how the duplicates could have been kept within the groups.